# ListView Selected Item Style Override

Tags: wpf

I have a WPF ListView that I'm trying to apply a custom style too... primarily I want to make the background of the listview box transparent with no border... and I want to override the highlighted and selected item styles.  The default highlight is a semi-transparent blue and the selected item is grey.  I'd like to override these in order to customize them.  I've followed several threads and tutorials... including this [**one**](https://wpftutorial.net/ListBoxSelectionBackground.html) but, my highlight and selected items remain in the default style.  Here's what I have.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style x:Key="ListViewStyle" TargetType="ListView">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"></Setter>
            <Style.Resources>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Red" />
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Green" />
            </Style.Resources>
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>

....

<ListView Style="{StaticResource ListViewStyle}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=DataContext.Current" >
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="local:Cases">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <!-- Some UI Controls Here  -->
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This approach of trying to override the system colours doesn't work on Windows 8 and later.

You need to modify the `ControlTemplate` of the `ListViewItem` container.

You can copy the default template into your XAML markup by right-clicking on the `ListView` in design mode in Visual Studio or in Blend and choose Edit Additional Templates->Edit Generated Item Container (ItemContainerStyle) and then edit it as per your requirements by for example changing the `Color` properties of the `SolidColorBrush`es:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=DataContext.Current" >
    <ListView.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="FocusVisual">
            <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Rectangle Margin="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="1 2"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Item.MouseOver.Background" Color="Red"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Item.MouseOver.Border" Color="#a826A0Da"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Item.SelectedInactive.Background" Color="#3DDADADA"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Item.SelectedInactive.Border" Color="#FFDADADA"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Item.SelectedActive.Background" Color="#3D26A0DA"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Item.SelectedActive.Border" Color="#FF26A0DA"/>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="4,1"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding HorizontalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource FocusVisual}"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                        <Border x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <MultiTrigger>
                                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
                                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource Item.MouseOver.Background}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource Item.MouseOver.Border}"/>
                            </MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger>
                                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="False"/>
                                    <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource Item.SelectedInactive.Background}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource Item.SelectedInactive.Border}"/>
                            </MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger>
                                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="True"/>
                                    <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource Item.SelectedActive.Background}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource Item.SelectedActive.Border}"/>
                            </MultiTrigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListView.Resources>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="local:Cases">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <!-- Some UI Controls Here  -->
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Thanks mm8.  Nice explanation.  Is there a way to assign the listview resources to this particular list?  Or is it automatically supposed to override the style since it's inside the ListView tag?  The reason I ask is that I'm not getting any changes to the style when I used the above code (even if I change the SolidColorBrush values).

Comment: It is automatically supposed to override the default template provided that you put the ListViewItem style inside <ListView.Resources> and *don't* specify an x:Key for the style. You can also set set the ItemContainerStyle property of the ListView to the custom/overridden ListViewItem style.

Comment: Can you clarify "don't specify an x:Key for the style"?  If I'm reading correctly, you mean that I'm supposed to take out the  _x:Key="FocusVisual"_ from the <Style> tag right under the <ListView.Resources> tag.  However, if I do that, I get an error that says, "All objects added to an IDictionary must have a Key attribute or some other type of key associated with them".

Comment: No, just from the *ListViewItem* style. Try to copy the sample markup I provided. Make sure that you don't set the Style property of the ListView.