# WPF listview selecteditem style

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

can you help me, by default wpf listview have such style for selected item 
[image]

But i need to make it like solid background on selected item like this

[image]

How i can make this?

Comment: I received this in inbox https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42235802/listview-selected-item-style-override/42236093#42236093 and it what i need.

Comment: @mm8 sorry, i didn't notice it in first time. Thank you. It strange that link without any refs was in inbox, so i am not figured out from where it goes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ListView Selected Item Style Override](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42235802/listview-selected-item-style-override)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Windows 7 you could override the system color brushes:

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Style.Resources>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Blue"/>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="White"/>
            </Style.Resources>
        </Style>
    </ListView.Resources>
    ...
</ListView>
```

On Windows 8 and later you should override the control template of the `ListViewItem` as explained here:

[ListView Selected Item Style Override](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42235802/listview-selected-item-style-override/42236093#42236093)

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this via `ControlTemplate`. See here: https://blog.jsinh.in/change-background-color-of-selected-listboxitem-listbox-in-wpf/

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
            <Border x:Name="Bd"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                    Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                    SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                  SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                                  VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
            </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive"
                             Value="False" />                          
                        <Condition Property="IsSelected"
                             Value="True" />
                     </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                     <Setter Property="Background"
                             TargetName="Bd"
                             Value="DarkOrange" />
                </MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive"
                                   Value="True" />
                        <Condition Property="IsSelected"
                                   Value="True" />
                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="Background"
                            TargetName="Bd"
                            Value="OrangeRed" />
                </MultiTrigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
</Style>
```